# Matlab Mcr 7.8 is not working on windows server 2019

Tags: .net, matlab, exe, matlab-compiler

I have a .NET executable that was compiled using MATLAB Compiler 7.8. The executable worked fine on systems running Microsoft Server 2012. However, when we attempted to run the executable on Windows Server 2019, we encountered an error stating that the MATLAB DLLs for version 7.8 were not available. To resolve this, I installed MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR) version 7.8 on the system, which resolved the DLL not found issue. However, the executable is now getting stuck on the console window and not functioning. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?